# Spring MVC: Adding JAXB to the classpath so that it automatically serializes XML

Tags: spring, maven-2, spring-mvc, xml-serialization, jaxb

According to Spring MVC documentation, `<mvc:annotation-driven/>` configures support for JSON if Jackson is in the classpath, and support for XML if JAXB is present in the classpath. Simply by adding a Jackson dependency to my pom.xml, I get JSON support to work! (see: [Ajax Simplification in Spring 3.0](http://blog.springsource.com/2010/01/25/ajax-simplifications-in-spring-3-0/))

However, after trying to access the same service with accept header "application/xml", I get a 406 Not Acceptable response. What's the simplest way to get JAXB in the classpath? What is necessary to enable support for XML MarshallingHttpMessageConverter?

**Update**

Taking a look at AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser, I can see what defines if "jaxb2Present". I set a breakpoint around line 179 to see if the Jaxb2RootElementHttpMessageConverter is indeed being registered like the MappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter is. It isn't...

*What's the simplest way to add JAXB to the classpath to make it automatically serialize my XML requests?*

Answer (score 2):

It should work. Make sure that the object being returned has `@XmlRootElement` annotation as required by JAXB.

Comment: I also have the same problem, and it doesn't work like so. I have another question about this, but with all my configurations and classes specified (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55381597/in-spring-mvc-what-is-the-correct-configuration-for-using-jaxb-annotations-for) and all seems right.. Spring MVC just doesn't work so simply with XML.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Java 6, JAXB is already on the classpath.  If you're using Java 5, you'll need to add a [reference implementation](http://jaxb.java.net/) yourself.

If you're using Maven, you can add to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: In addition to the reference implementation there are the MOXy (http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php), and JaxMe (http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/) JAXB implementations.